# Formatting the date?

Tags: javascript, date, format

i have a field where you have to enter the date but i also have a script on that field which automatically inserts the current date. The problem i have is that the date is formatted like M/DD/YYYY 00:00:00 AM/PM but i just wanted it to be like DD/MM/YY.

Here is my current code by the way :

```
<b>Date of Registration:</b> <input type="text" id="txtregodate" name="regodate">

<script type="text/javascript">
var now = new Date ();
document.getElementById('txtregodate').value = now.toLocaleString();
</script>
```

Is there a way to format that function i'm using in that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this... this will give DD/MM/YY format date

```
var now = new Date ();
document.getElementById('txtregodate').value = now.getDate() + '/' + (now.getMonth() + 1)+ '/' + (now.getYear()%100);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a great library for this stuff: http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

(It's all about utilising the `Date` methods (`getDate`, `getMonth`, `getYear`, `getFullYear`) and concatenating them as strings. That's basically it.

```
var now = new Date();
document.getElementById('txtregodate').value = now.getDate()+'/'+(now.getMonth()+1)+'/'+(now.getFullYear()%100);
```

You can get this info from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Comment: For some reason that comes up with the wrong month?

Comment: Fixed it, but the other guy got there.